# MongoDB push to nested array using Linq expressions

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

To execute a push using de MongoDB C# Driver, I need to instantiate a `FieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, MyNestedArrayType[]>`.

I know that I can instantiate this `FieldDefinition` using strings...

```cs
FieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, NestedArrType[]> field = "MyArray.$.MyNestedArray";
```

I tried the same using Linq expressions, like this:

```cs
FieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, NestedArrType[]> field =
    new ExpressionFieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, NestedArrType[]>(
        doc => doc.MyArray.First().MyNestedArray
    );
```

But I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the
>   serialization information for doc =>
>   doc.MyArray.First().MyNestedArray.

Is there any way to create a `FieldDefinition` of a nested array using Linq expression that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-1` as an array index to represent positional operator (`$`):

```
FieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, NestedArrType[]> field =
            new ExpressionFieldDefinition<MyMongoDocumentType, NestedArrType[]>(
                doc => doc.MyArray[-1].MyNestedArray
            );
```

To make it work you also need additional query condition on `MyArray` which can be done using `ElemMatch` in MongoDB .NET driver, for instance:

```
Builders<MyMongoDocumentType>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.MyArray, f => f.NestedId == 1);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I recommend using `#pragma warning disable CS0251` at the beginning of the file and `#pragma warning restore CS0251` at the end, to avoid the warning on the negative index.